# Is it possible to calculate this Feynman diagram?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

[image]

where the photon is virtual and the others(mesons) are scalar.

So, I had tried to calculate this as follows,

$$M^{\mu}=\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2 \pi)^4} Tr[\frac{1}{\not{k}-m} \frac{1}{\not{k}-\not{q'}-m} \gamma^{\mu}]$$

with Feynman parameters and the dimensional regularization.

But, in my result, the amplitude for this diagram has no contribution.

Do I have some misunderstanding?

Comment: What is the vertex the photon is attached to? Scalar - scalar - photon - spinor - spinor?

Comment: yes! Do you have comments?

Comment: I'm curious in what theory there is an interaction $\bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi A_\mu \bar \phi \phi$.....Where did you come across this process?

Comment: It is just an example in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral representation is correct and your assessment of the diagram providing a null contribution is also correct. This is a general feature under the premise of Furry’s theorem, which says the vev of a time ordered product of an *odd* number of vector current insertions onto a *closed fermion loop* vanishes. At the Feynman diagram level, this translates into ‘if your diagram has an odd number of photon attachments onto the closed loop, then it may safely be ignored’ by virtue of the theorem.  It’s a statement of $C$-parity conservation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, I thought that the Furry's theorem is allowed only photons. i.e. one photon with one loop and three photons with one loop. But, in this case, mesons are also attached in a loop. Is it also applied to this? And I think, usually, the odd photon with one loop diagrams is not zero itself. Instead, the summation of each channel is zero. I wonder what is your opinion about it.

Comment: The theorem also extends to the bosons of QCD, i.e. the gluon but I don't think mesons come into the picture.  Indeed, diagrams usually cancel pairwise (reflected in the time ordering at the level of the correlator) but since you know they will collectively vanish you can tag and set them to zero in any calculation from the outset.

Comment: Also, btw you should not put arrows on your scalar lines in your diagram. The time ordering is already manifest, so I believe this is why you found the diagram identically vanishing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I need more time to understand it exactly.